# What is the name of this control? Two scrollable lists with a direction bar

Tags: user-interface, scroll, picker

I need to find a control but I don't know what it is called. The control has two scrollable lists, A and B. A starts out with many choices, while B is empty. There are two buttons between the lists. One let's you move whatever is selected in A to B. The other let's you move whatever is selected in B to A. I have seen these controls often but don't know what they are called. Anyone know?

Comment: Mostly it's self-created controls...

Answer (score 1):

In the Primeface framework, it is named `PickList`. See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml

Comment: That is it. Thx

Comment: Do not hesitate to validate the answer ;)